# Extend list by repeating individual elements in python

Tags: python, list

Is there an easier way to achieve the below?

```
lst = []
repetitions = 3
for elem in range(3):
    lst  += [elem] * repetitions
```

this turns [0,1,2] into [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]

Comment: Also using `itertools.chain`, you can do: `list(chain.from_iterable([[x]*3 for x in [0,1,2]]))`

Comment: You should be getting `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension):

```
print([item for item in lst for i in range(3)])
```

Using [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
lst = [0,1,2]
print(list(np.repeat(lst,3)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) with two loops:

```
>>> [elem for elem in range(3) for _ in range(repetitions)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is your friend:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(i, 3) for i in range(1, 4)))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
print(list(chain.from_iterable(([x]*3 for x in [0,1,2]))))
#[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about easier, but itertools has `repeat`, so

```py
lst = [r for e in <items to repeat> for r in repeat(e, repetitions)
```

or

```py
lst = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(e, repetitions) for e in <items to repeat>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print([ i for i in range(3) for j in range(3)])
```

Try this, this is nested list comprehension, and just one lines pretty much what you do there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
lst = []
repetitions = 3
for elem in range(2):
   for _ in range(elem+1):
       lst.append(elem)
```

This should be faster than adding lists.